# Pentagon vertices

Tags: probability

Consider a pentagon. Each of the pentagon's vertices is assigned with a value with equal probability: $1$, $2$, or $3$. Then each edge is assigned the sum of the numbers of the adjacent vertices. I wish to calculate the the probability that all 5 numbers assigned to each edge are even. I thought I could do:

$$P=P\left(\text{edge 1 is even}\right)\cdot...\cdot P\left(\text{edge 5 is even}\right)$$

But then I realized it wouldn't work because there isn't independence between the events. I fail to see how to solve this problem without calculating all the possibilities.

Comment: If you assign one of the vertices an odd number, the only way for the two edges from that vertex to get even numbers is that the adjacent vertices are also assigned odd number. The same logic follows for other edges.... The same way if you start with even number, all vertices will have to be even.

Comment: Thank you. I though then $P = (\frac{1}{3})^{5}+(\frac{2}{3})^{5}$ because one option is every vertex is even ($2$) and the other one is everything is odd ($1$ or $3$) but that doesn't seem to be the correct answer. Am I missing something?

Comment: Based on what the question states, it seems correct to me unless I am missing something.

Comment: Thank you, there was a mistake in the answers sheet.

Comment: you are welcome